# Build Matrix depending on different conditions in a vector

Tags: r, matrix

Please I need your help! I have a matrix like this

```
       A   B   C
 [1,] 101 201 301
 [2,] 102 202 302
 [3,] 103 203 303
 [4,] 104 204 304
 [5,] 105 205 305
 [6,] 106 206 306
 [7,] 107 207 307
 [8,] 108 208 308
 [9,] 109 209 309
[10,] 110 210 310
```

and a vector with different values like this:
categories <- c("A","B","A","C","A","C","B")

In the result I want to create the following matrix in R:

```
     A   B   A   C   A   C   B
1  101 201 101 301 101 301 201
2  102 202 102 302 102 302 202
3  103 203 103 303 103 303 203
4  104 204 104 304 104 304 204
5  105 205 105 305 105 305 205
6  106 206 106 306 106 306 206
7  107 207 107 307 107 307 207
8  108 208 108 308 108 308 208
9  109 209 109 309 109 309 209
10 110 210 110 310 110 310 210
```

Unfortunately, I'm just a beginner in R and so I have developed the following procedure:

```
#Create Example Data
A <- seq(101,110,1)
B <- seq(201,210,1)
C <- seq(301,310,1)
rawdata.m <- matrix(nrow=10,ncol=3,data=c(A,B,C))
colnames(rawdata.m) <- c("A","B","C")

categories <- c("A","B","A","C","A","C","B")

#build new matrix dependent on vector
if (categories[1]=="A") result.m <- data.frame(rawdata.m[,1])
if (categories[1]=="B") result.m <- data.frame(rawdata.m[,2])
if (categories[1]=="C") result.m <- data.frame(rawdata.m[,3])

for(i in 2:length(categories))
{
  if (categories[i]=="A") result.m <- data.frame(result.m, rawdata.m[,1])
  if (categories[i]=="B") result.m <- data.frame(result.m, rawdata.m[,2])
  if (categories[i]=="C") result.m <- data.frame(result.m, rawdata.m[,3])
}
colnames(result.m) <- categories

print(result.m)
```

This procedure does not look very elegant and is not fast if you use larger matrices. Do you know a better procedure?

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I must commend you on asking a very good first question.  It's clear and 100% reproducible, +1

Comment: Last, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It's a lot easier than you think:

```
rawdata.m[, categories]
```

Comment: Awesome! It is really a lot easier! Thank you very much!